AzureDevops yml pipline if condition for a variable not working
variables:
- name: RerunFailedTestCase
  ${{if and(ge(variables['system.clock.hour'], 19), lt(variables['system.clock.hour'], 23)) }}:
    value: 'false'
  ${{ else }}:
    value: 'true'

have created a variable on my yaml pipeline. But this never works according to the condition i have set in it.
I want it to rerun the value of $(RerunFailedTestCase) as false if run between 19:00 and 23:00. and as true for any other time

Hi @Mayank Raghuwanshi, have you tried to create an output variable RerunFailedTestCase and set its value based on the current system? Did it work for you?

Your expression itself is right. I guess it may have something to do with system.clock.hour, I don't find the information about this variable.
As a workaround, you can create an output variable RerunFailedTestCase and set its value based on the current system in PowerShell. See the example below.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- powershell: |
    $currentHour = (Get-Date).Hour
    echo $currentHour
    if ($currentHour -ge 18 -and $currentHour -lt 23) {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RerunFailedTestCase]false"
    } else {
       Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RerunFailedTestCase]true"
    }
  displayName: 'Set RerunFailedTestCase Variable'

- script: echo 'The value of RerunFailedTestCase is $(RerunFailedTestCase)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  condition: eq(variables['RerunFailedTestCase'], 'true')
  displayName: 'Run tests'
  inputs:
    ...

Result:


If I'm not mistaken, there's no way to get the system date at compile time, so it won't be possible to use template expressions such as ${{ if... }} to do what you want.
As a workaround, you can:

Parse special variable pipeline.startTime in order to  extract the hour in which the pipeline starts
Set a stage/job/steps condition to check the value of the variable

Full working example:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  - name: pipelineStartHour
    value: "$[format('{0:HH}', pipeline.startTime)]" # runtime variable

jobs:
  - job: 'ReRunFailedTestCases'
    displayName: 'Re-run failed test cases'
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: |
        echo "$(pipelineStartHour)"
      displayName: 'Display pipeline start hour (UTC)'
    condition: | 
      and(
        succeeded(), 
        in(variables['pipelineStartHour'], '19', '20', '21', '22')
      )

Please note that the default time zone for pipeline.startTime is UTC.
